# How to scroll in flowlayout panel without showing scrollbar in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I am working on a touch screen POS in WinForms.

I have a flowlayoutpanel and add buttons dynamically but I dont want to show a scrollbar.

I use 2 buttons to scroll instead, so please help me how to scroll without showing a scrollbar

Comment: its not working for me, can you post the settings and configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two buttons btnLeft and btnRight and try this code :

```
private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flowPanelItemCategory.Location.X <= xpos)
    {
        xmin = flowPanelItemCategory.HorizontalScroll.Minimum;
        if (flowPanelItemCategory.Location.X >= xmin)
        {
            xpos -= 100;
            flowPanelItemCategory.Location = new Point(xpos, 0);
        }
    }
}

private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flowPanelItemCategory.Location.X <= xpos)
    {
        xmax = flowPanelItemCategory.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;
        if (flowPanelItemCategory.Location.X < xmax)
        {
            xpos += 100;
            flowPanelItemCategory.Location = new Point(xpos, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working for me, can you post the settings and configuration?

Answer (score 8):

Try placing the FlowLayoutPanel inside another panel with these properties:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = false;
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
```

From here, you have to control yourself the location of the FlowLayoutPanel1 inside your panel (which should also have `AutoScroll = false;`) based on your two buttons.

Comment: can i add easing or page scrolling to this. by page scrolling i mean. on click of left oe right. all visible control is scrolled off showing new sets of visible ones