# How to scroll flow layout panel with button click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll

I am adding dyanmic controls(textboxes)  in flowlayout panel.I want the controls to scroll when I click on a button(up or down button).The scroll buttons should not be visible.How can I achieve this.Any suggestions?? It is windows application using c#.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scroll in flowlayout panel without showing scrollbar in windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980771/how-to-scroll-in-flowlayout-panel-without-showing-scrollbar-in-windows-form)

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
int yLoc = 0;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flowPanel.Location.Y <= yLoc && flowPanel.Location.Y >= flowPanel.VerticalScroll.Minimum)
    {
        yLoc -= 50;
        flowPanel.Location = new Point(0, yLoc);
    }
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flowPanel.Location.Y <= yLoc && flowPanel.Location.Y < flowPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
    {
        yLoc += 50;
        flowPanel.Location = new Point(0, yLoc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting verticalscroll.minimum value as 0 always.why is it so?Should I add vertical scroll bar to the panel

Comment: Also if suppose I have 50 controls oly first visible controls (eg 10 controls) are only displayed remaining 4o controls didnt appear